# Android Bootstrap what is that really, what does it do?

Tags: android, android-bootstrap

According to this link [www.androidbootstrap.com/‎](http://www.androidbootstrap.com/) I am wondering what does it really do, what is for? Am I supposed to use it?

I've read all text on this main page but I am still confused and I do not know should I use it.
The main problem is I don't see the point. Could someone tell me what is it for?

I am open for new technologies but here is the example where I don't understand, but they say that using their package will shorten my work on application.

Regards and I am looking for any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering what does it really do

It generates a skeleton Android project containing specific libraries. It is reminiscent of the new-project wizard in Eclipse, just supporting more third-party libraries, particularly ones that may be a bit of a challenge to get working together.

Comment: What about responsible design? I heard that "bootstrap" is able set adjustable view for different screen sizes. That you can for example set for small views add gridview with 3 columns and for bigger 5 columns. Is it true? Or maybe there is any other bootstrap for that kind of job?

Comment: so there is no any bootstrap which would generate auto customizable view project for android?

Comment: @deadfish: Since I have no idea what you mean by "auto customizable view project" means, I cannot answer that. You asked what AndroidBootstrap.com does, and I answered that. You may wish to ask a separate StackOverflow question, where you inquire about app templates or "bootstrap" sites that cover whatever it is that you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at this project to provide a quick set up for actionbarsherlock and dagger DI.

I think it’s a good idea as it seeks to provide an android template, with an out the box solution including sherlock and dagger. But I couldn’t get it working on eclipse, and the forum had a lot of people saying the same (I think its designed for Intelij IDEA)

I also looked at androidkickstartr which is more mature, but again had import issues, so just made my own template and imported sherlock and dagger